# How can I implement a shared library in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for something similar conceptually to a Windows DLL.  As a concrete example, suppose I have a function encrypt that I would like to share across several unrelated projects.  If I want to change the implementation ideally I can do so once and every project has access to the new implementation.  Is there a mechanism for doing this in Node.js?

Comment: Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320446/5646315). It might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [document](http://howtonode.org/how-to-module) especially the section "Writing a Library"

> If you are writing a program that is intended to be used by others,
>   then the most important thing to specify in your package.json file is
>   the main module. This is the module that is the entry point to your
>   program.

and

> If you have a lot of JavaScript code, then the custom is to put it in
>   the ./lib folder in your project.
>
> Specify a main module in your package.json file. This is the module
>   that your users will load when they do require('your-library'). This
>   module should ideally expose all of the functionality in your library.
>
> If you want your users to be able to load sub-modules from the "guts"
>   of your library, then they'll need to specify the full path to them.
>   That is a lot of work to document! It's better and more future-proof
>   to simply specify a main module, and then, if necessary, have ways to
>   dynamically load what they need.
>
> For example, you might have a flip library that is a collection of
>   widget objects, defined by files in the flip/lib/widgets/*.js files.
>   Rather than having your users do require('flip/lib/widgets/blerg.js')
>   to get the blerg widget, it's better to have something like:
>   require('flip').loadWidget('blerg').