# Call C++ library from Node.js (Node addons / node-ffi)

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, node-ffi

I'm trying to integrate an external C++ library (I have access to the .so file as well as the header files) into my Node.js application.

After a lot of research my options are reduced to:

1. Writing a [Node addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
2. Use [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi)

From node-ffi's gitHub's definition I can't tell if it will or will not work directly on C++ libraries:

> node-ffi is a Node.js addon for loading and calling dynamic libraries using pure JavaScript. It can be used to create bindings to native libraries without writing any C++ code.

So the questions I have are:

- Does option 1) imply rewriting in some way the external C++ library?
- Is node-ffi able to call directly to C++ libraries without any kind of C wrapper I'd have to write?

I'm no expert when it comes to C/C++ so if I missed something basic for you to be able to answer please let me know so I can improve my question.

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783023/node-ffi-vs-node-extension-for-accessing-existing-c-functionality?rq=1 but I think it does not fully answer my questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

node-ffi seems to be primarily for C programs.  I went through this in the last week, and found much better luck with node addons.  What you have to do is write a shim between the C++ code in the library and node.js.  In my case, I needed to encode and decode packets for a security protocol, so I made node buffers that contained the packets, and wrote C++ code that got the data out of the buffers, then send the data to my C code that encoded and decoded packets.

This page:  http://luismreis.github.io/node-bindings-guide/docs/returning.html  has some great examples of how to get data in and out of node.js buffers in C++.

Comment: ffi works with C++, just use extern "C" to define your lib's interface (as you would with anything written in C++ that may be consumed also by C) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783023/node-ffi-vs-node-extension-for-accessing-existing-c-functionality?rq=1 for details.

Answer (score 3):

[nbind](https://github.com/charto/nbind#readme) now makes it easier to write Node.js addons using external C++ libraries. You basically create a new source file including the library headers, the nbind headers and some macro calls listing the library's classes and methods. Then nbind handles the rest.

[libui-node](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node) is a real-world example using nbind to call [libui](https://github.com/andlabs/libui) for generating user interfaces with native widgets from Node.js. There's also a [short tutorial](https://github.com/charto/nbind/blob/master/doc/vg-tutorial.md) how to create bindings for [vg](https://github.com/vgteam/vg), a bioinformatics-related C++ library.

Answer (score 2):

What is missing from the other answer? I am happy to help. The code example there is written in C++. I am illustrating how people (who make libraries in C or C++) define an external interface for others to consume. The point of ffi is that you write your wrapper in whatever language you are using (in this case javascript) rather than C/C++ (as in the case of node extensions.)  If your original library is a shared DLL used in other things, it already has an interface, you just need to write wrapper-code in javascript to tell node how it works, rather than write something in C++ and expose it in a native nodejs library.

Comment: You can find info here https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial which is an example of wrapping a few methods of sqlite. The fact that the lib is C or C++ is irrelevant, just that it defines an interface (like all shared libraries do.)

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty easy way to link any your library(`.so .dll .a`). You should add library with correct path in `binging.gyp` file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ],
      "libraries": [
            "path/toYourLibrary/yourLibName.dll or yourLibName.so"
          ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

Also there is more simpler way to write good addons using `nan`. Check link for more information [github link](https://github.com/nodejs/nan)