# How to import c++ (cpp file) as lib/module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, import, module

Now I'm struggling to find the way to import a cpp file as library or module in nodejs. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? Thank you.

I found a website about 'SWIG and Javascript' and the information looks similar to what i think. Please check this link. http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html#Javascript

However i'm worrying about that doesn't support on Windows but i'm not sure. :-(
See `26.2.2 Running Tests and Examples` in website.

Please let me know whether it supports windows or not.

Comment: Pos dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636017/call-c-library-from-node-js-node-addons-node-ffi

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html